# JQuery to expand all collapsible sections of a page (from external website)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The page contains multiple sections. Each section is represented by a TD block (see code below), the actual page would show a ">" icon (hovering over it shows the a href: javascript:void(0)), and when manually clicked, it would expand the section by a POST call to the endpoint from the SPAN block.

```
<td id="abc-parent" data-column="parent" data-row="abc" class="mt-cell mt-center">
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
    <span class="a-declarative" data-action="myitable-fetch-rows" data-myitable-fetch-rows="{&quot;endpoint&quot;:&quot;/hz/inventory/variation?parentRecord=abc&quot;,&quot;rowId&quot;:&quot;abc&quot;}">
        <div class="mt-variation-icon mt-variation-expand"/>
    </span>
</a></td>
```

I am looking to create a bookmarklet containing a line of JQuery. And when called, it would expand all collapsible sections of a page.

What I mean is something like this (note this does not achieve what I described above):

```
javascript:jQuery('.a-declarative').each(function(i,e){e.click()})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the "Trigger" function:

> **.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters ] )** Description: Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.
>
> https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

So your code above should be something like:

```
$('.a-declarative').trigger('click');
```

Use at your own risk as this is not a very stable way to trigger events.

Comment: This did the trick! It does bring me to a blank page, but if i add an invalid character in the end (don't ask me why...), it was able to expand all sections and stay on the same page! Thanks!
javascript:jQuery('.a-declarative').trigger('click');x

Answer (score 1):

Create a global class `.active` for all the expandable areas (make sure they all have it, even if you have to add it after another `class="another active"`)

Assure `.active` is the expanded state. Then call it like below.

```
$('.item').toggleClass('active');
```

[Simple jsfiddle demo of this.](http://jsfiddle.net/9y3Wq/53/)

---

If for some reason you can't alter the mark-up to make a global active class, you may have to call it with all the 'expanded selectors' (but should be no reason for this)

```
$('.item').toggleClass('active expanded open');
```

For help on the [bookmarklet](http://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/) aspect; this is a cool link that should help you out; but all you should be doing is defining the above in a function and then trigger with a `.click()`  event.

---

**Update!** I just sent another pointer via comment section below; but you know you can add a class `.active` via jQuery to all the toggles that share same class or ID. But you will still have to investigate how the toggles were built on this external website for you to incorporate the expanded state with your new `.active` state. There is no way for use to know this as you didn't post that code; but it's typically found in the `.css` pretty easily.

```
$('td').find('.mt-center').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but unfortunately, I have no control over the page at all (it is not my website).. The code you see above is what I have to work with..

Comment: Well you have to figure out how the expanded state of these toggles occur (use chrome developer tools to view source and inspect), it is usually by class. Find that class, grab it and call it as I suggested! Creating a click function as a bookmarklet is easy, find how the toggles operate and what causes them to open and replicate within your function.

Comment: Great additional information! Although it did not exactly solve my case. I up-voted your answer because it may be helpful for others.